# How to read message from Topic in ActiveMQ + PHP + Stomp?

Tags: php, activemq-classic, stomp

I have to read messages from Topic in ActiveMQ + PHP(Stomp), for that I did below code,

```
try {
    $stomp = new Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613');
} catch (StompException $e) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$topic='/topic/mytopic';
$stomp->subscribe($topic);
$frame = $stomp->readFrame();
var_dump($frame);
```

But when I got result in `var_dump($frame)` as `bool(false)`. Instead of that in my topic there is some message. which I could not get it.

Can anybody suggest me solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.* Please include your expected results, your attempted solutions, and why they didn't work. Please see the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

the publisher is down?you only can receive the message when the topic message publish.

you can test at this step:
1、run publisher command 
2、run the comsumer command(the first run publisher no quit)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solutions.

for topic please refer https://github.com/dejanb/stomp-php 
Here you need to install library through composer. `$ php composer.phar install` 
More detail refer link.

Thank you,

Comment: for other Cross Language Clients
http://activemq.apache.org/cross-language-clients.html